# how to get image from iPhone gallery titanium?

Tags: iphone, image, mobile, titanium, gallery

I need to select an image from iPhone photo gallery and upload to server. Im having 10kb image in gallery.

```
Titanium.Media.openPhotoGallery({
                    success : function(e) {
                        var image = e.media;

                    },
                    cancel : function() {
                        Ti.API.info('user cancelled galary.');
                    },
                    error : function(error) {
                        var alert = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
                            title : 'Sorry!',
                            message : 'Error: ' + error.code
                        });
                        alert.show();
                    },
                    mediaTypes : Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO
                });
```

I used the code above, e.media returns image of 40kb size. why??

Comment: Can't help you, based solely on what you've provided. You need to provide an example of how you're failing to upload it to your server.

Answer (score 1):

Might be error from your server side. check if there's restrictions for a certain format or size of the file. by the way I am using this code to upload the file and its working fine

```
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.onerror = errorCallback;
    xhr.onload = loadCallback;
    xhr.onsendstream = progressCallback;
    // open the client
    xhr.setTimeout(30000);
    xhr.open('POST', url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("ContentType", "image/jpeg");

    // send the data
    xhr.send({
        media : media
    });
```

Comment: upload working fine, thanks. but why the size of the image from e.media is larger(iPhone only) than the original?